# What is the reason django.db.utils.Error

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-sql-database

What is the reason for `django.db.utils.Error`, Tried to locate error however I cannot find correct reason.

This error I got with Azure Cloud services connection with SQL service.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well usually that means that something is wrong with the database. But with this amount of information, it is impossible to tell what exactly is wrong.

Comment: This question is meaningless without context. There are any number of conditions which could cause an application to raise this exception. Please provide code snippets and the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you using pymssql and FreeTDS? Please use them. Let us know if you need information how to install FreeTDS and how to connect to Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Enable logging for better troubleshooting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo
(1) I'm using django-pyodbc-azure and it's premium plan.
(2) Enabled detail log however I could not find any useful information.

Comment: @AlexForbes
code snippets:
`from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:

   SQL = "Insert into table(field1, field1)value(value1, value2)"
   
cursor.execute(SQL)
`

Comment: Yes @WillemVanOnsem I'm trying to extract log but not getting exact log which is to be useful